# Activity Tab not appearing immediately on activity timeline after changing default view

Tags: lightning-record-page, activity-timeline

I had activity timeline already added on one of the Lightning pages on account, but the default activities view was later changed to "Related Lists". So I restored the view to "Activity Timeline", but the Activity tab did not appear on the timeline.
However, when I closed the browser and relaunched it, without making any changes, the Activity tab started appearing on the timeline. I have observed this behavior multiple times. Is there any different route to achieve this? As far as I understand, default view must be changed, but since facing this issue, is there any way I could avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue experienced sometimes with Lightning pages. I too have faced this issue with Activity Timeline, wherein I had performed the below steps after changing the configuration (for instance, changing the default view in your case)-

1. Did a hard refresh (by emptying the page cache)
2. Logged out of the current user and logged in again.

However, to my surprise, even after the 2nd step, the activity timeline wasn't added on the page. When I logged in to my application from an incognito window, that's when I was able to see the timeline getting reflected on my page.

So honestly there is no another route to achieve this. As you've mentioned, you could see the results after restarting your browser - which itself is indicative of the fact that the configuration was correct. So you won't have to bother about this much. If you face the issue in future as well, you can try what I did - Go incognito, or log out of your user and restart the browser.

Cheers!